Differences between internal routes and external routes with / in parameter
Update: I have noticed that it's not the / which is a problem but the . so it looks like any url with . is not recognized in external routing. What's the recommended procedure? Example:
/doc/some/path.With/dots.txt

This works with internal routes but not with externals.
Original issue:
For a blazor page, I have a Url Pattern of
@page "/{area}/{*Id}"

When routing to
/doc/some/path/to/a/doc

This works perfectly when arriving from an internal route. However, on F5, the blazor component is not hit, i.e. it doesn't recognize the pattern.
I have also tried to explicitly escape the Id as
/doc/some%2Fpath%2Fto%2Fa%2Fdoc

with the same result: the internal route works, the external doesn't. Do I need to change my config? Is this a bug in blazor?

Net version?  Interactivity type [Server/WebAssembly/Auto]?  Interactivity location [Global or Page/Component]?

dotnet 8 Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web 8.0.7, Server.
Copilot suggested to replace . with %2E (which Uri.EncodeDataString doesn't do). Updon doing it manually, Blazor is "smart" enough to decode %2E to . and then again fail.
I am tired of this, need to roll my own encoding anyway and will just replace the period by a sequence of my choosing. this will outsmart Blazor...

This is actually a duplicate. Have found the answer here:
How do I route in client-side blazor with a string route parameter containing dots (.)?
Please go and upvote.
